# What do you call the sides of the bench-like seats in subway trains?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

This is an example (from a train in Japan). I circles the relevant section:

[image]

(Another problem is, I'm not sure whether to call those seats "chairs" or "benches.")

Example sentence:

> When the passengers entered, I retreated until my back hit the __

Comment: Definitely not "chairs" - a chair is something for one person, with legs.  I'd just call them *seats*.  *Benches* is OK although [a bench is usually something freestanding](https://www.google.com/search?q=bench&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi21PjM4IXcAhVPs1kKHYwWAP4Q_AUICygC&biw=1233&bih=827).

Comment: I think it's actually a [banquette](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/banquette) ...a word I would avoid like the plague for describing train seats ;)

Comment: I think most native speakers would call that flat surface the **side** of the seat, just as you have done, or perhaps the **side panel**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the railways have a specific word for them - but if you were to use it would anyone outside the industry recognise it for what it was?

You could call it a [stanchion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stanchion) I suppose, but you could escape the dilemma altogether & just call it a metal bar, or pole or  'metal upright'... or for further distinction, 'the metal upright at the doorway, separating the entrance from the passenger compartment'... at the serious risk of becoming verbose ;)

Edit: for the other problem, use the same avoidance tactic - call them seats.

Another reason to avoid being too specific is the diversity of tube/subway trains across the world. That photo is of quite an old Japanese train, but compare it to a modern London tube - that's one heck of a lot of metalwork to hold onto, & no-one but the designer is ever going to distinguish between them.

[image]

Any reader is going to imagine their own local transportation, if they live in a city with an underground railway, or if not, one they saw on TV.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So maybe I should just call those "the side of the seats." I wanted to call those bars "metal poles" but I think your suggestions are better.

Comment: metal pole wouldn't be bad. I went for upright just as it gives a 'direction'. I'd avoid handrail or anything like that as it *could* be misinterpreted as being horizontal, even if further context removed the ambiguity. I think the overall implication is to treat it casually. Very few people on a tube are really thinking about what all the bits are called. Doors, seats, handrails/holds/straps... that's about as far as their technical awareness goes.